# SQL to find tables list in Snowflake where a column has a particular date value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find the list of tables in Snowflake where all these tables have same schema and a timestamp column should be < 30 days.

My goal here is to find the tables and delete rows from all those tables where timestamp is less than 30days. The tables are in same pattern except for a number at the end and I do not want to do this for all tables since I have more than 300 of them. I first want to get the list of those tables which have rows older than 30days and then insert them into another table before deleting from each of these tables.

This gives me the list of tables

```
select table_name from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'DIM_NAMES_%';
```

Now, I want to get only those tables whose

```
time_id < 30 days
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the age-old DBA technique of a SQL generator. First generate a UNION ALL query that finds the tables that have the old rows, then run it.

Step 1 - Generate the query:

```
select listagg('select \'' || TABLE_NAME || '\' as TABLE_WITH_OLD_ROW where exists (select 1 from ' || TABLE_NAME || 
               ' where time_id < dateadd(day, -30, current_timestamp) limit 1)','\nunion all\n') SQL_TO_RUN
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'DIM_NAMES_%';
;
```

Optionally, create some tables to test this:

```
-- Optionally create some tables to test.
create or replace table DIM_NAMES_1(time_id timestamp);
create or replace table DIM_NAMES_2(time_id timestamp);
create or replace table DIM_NAMES_3(time_id timestamp);

-- Insert an old timestamp in two, but not all three
insert into DIM_NAMES_1 select '2020-01-01';
insert into DIM_NAMES_2 select '2020-01-01';
```

This will generate a query that looks like this:

```
select 'DIM_NAMES_1' as TABLE_WITH_OLD_ROW where exists (select 1 from DIM_NAMES_1 where time_id < dateadd(day, -30, current_timestamp) limit 1)
union all
select 'DIM_NAMES_2' as TABLE_WITH_OLD_ROW where exists (select 1 from DIM_NAMES_2 where time_id < dateadd(day, -30, current_timestamp) limit 1)
union all
select 'DIM_NAMES_3' as TABLE_WITH_OLD_ROW where exists (select 1 from DIM_NAMES_3 where time_id < dateadd(day, -30, current_timestamp) limit 1)
;
```

Running the generated SQL with the union all across tables will find the ones we want:

| TABLE_WITH_OLD_ROW |
| --- |
| DIM_NAMES_1 |
| DIM_NAMES_2 |

If this is an ad-hoc or one time thing, this is all you'd need. If it's a regular requirement, this can be put into a SQL Script, stored procedure, etc.